# Ruby Printing variable within a String, Phone Validation

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to get the variables to output in a string. When I print the below it isn't formatting correctly with a new line for each title and variable.

```
    print "User: #{names}\nPhone: #{valid_phone?(number)}\n Email: #{email}"
```

I'm getting this output:

```
   User: ["john", "doe\n"] Phone: 555-555
   Email: johndoe@info.com
```

Output should appear as:

```
   User: John Doe
   Phone: (555)555-5555
   Email: johndoe@info.com
```

I'm also not getting the phone number to output in the format of (555)555-5555. Here is my full code. Thanks!!

```
  NAME_PATTERN = /([\w\-\']{2,})([\s]+)([\w\-\']{2,})/
  EMAIL_PATTERN = /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i
  PHONE_PATTERN = /^(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})$/

  def valid_name?(name)
    !!name.match(NAME_PATTERN)
  end

  puts "Enter your first and last name (John Doe): "

  while (name=gets)

  names = name.split(" ", 2)
  if valid_name?(name)
        puts "Great, that looks like it could work."
        break
        else
        puts "Invalid entry, please enter first and last name. To exit press ctrl+c."
    end
  end

  def valid_email?(email)
    !!email.match(EMAIL_PATTERN)
  end

  puts "Enter your email address (joe@info.com): "

  while (email = gets)

    if valid_email?(email)
        puts "Great, that looks like it could work."
        break
    else
        puts "Invalid email address entered. Please try again. To exit press ctrl+c."
    end
  end

  puts "Enter your phone number including area code (numbers only): "

  def valid_phone?(number)
    !!number.match(PHONE_PATTERN)
    number = number.to_s
    area_code = number.length == 10 ? "(#{number[0..2]}) " : '' 
    office_code = number[-7..-5] 
    specific_line = number[-4..-1]
    "#{area_code}#{office_code}-#{specific_line}"
  end

  while (number=gets)
       if valid_phone?(number)
        puts "Great, that looks like it could work."
    break
    else
        puts "Invalid phone number entered. Please try again. To exit press ctrl+c."
        end
  end

    print "User: #{names}\nPhone: #{valid_phone?(number)}\n Email: #{email}"
```

Comment: The best approach when posting a question is to strip the code down to the absolute minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem at hand. I'm seeing you post the same ever expanding chunk of code. Staying focused helps people understand your problem more quickly, and gives it a better chance of being answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your expected output replace your last line (`print`) with the following

```
puts "User: #{names.join(' ')}"
puts "Phone: #{valid_phone?(number)}"
puts "Email: #{email}"
```

Also change the line `number = number.to_s` to `number = number.chomp`

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your first problem of new line.

Add `names.join(",")` in last line Like below will work:

```
print "User: #{names.join(",")}\nPhone: #{valid_phone?(number.chomp)}\nEmail: #{email}"
```

but for the second issue of phone number, what problem you have?.